# How do I find the code for the current major mode?

Tags: elisp, major-mode

How do I find the elisp code for the major mode in use in the current buffer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The variable `major-mode` will be set to a symbol describing the mode.

If the mode was written anytime in recent history, that symbol will be a function that activates the mode.

So you can simply "find" the major mode's code.

`(find-function major-mode)`

Or interactively, run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-mode` and click the link to the source file.